# Listen click text in dynamically created iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, onclick, onclicklistener

I want to add event when click on text in iframe. This iframe created after the document has loaded. After created, there is document object `#document` created in iframe element. In this code, the click on text in iframe could not be catched.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../ext/plugins/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //add iframe
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            var html = '<body>Foo</body>';
            iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
            $('#iframe-holder').append(iframe);
        })
        $(document).on('click','#iframe-holder > iframe',function(){
            console.log('you have clicked text in iframe');
            //do something
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="iframe-holder">
        
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You've to attach the click handler to the document of the iframe, like `$($(#iframe-holder > iframe)[0].contentDocument).on('click', [text selector (optional)], function (e) {});`. Notice, that it's good to add all the parts to the iframe document, include the DTD, html and head parts in `html`  too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested both @Teemu and @Tanay answer . It works when I added in `document.addEventListener('load',function(event){//sucessfully fired when added here})` Then, I have change iframe.src to source document, `page1.html`.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../ext/plugins/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //add iframe
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            var html = '<body>Foo</body>';
            //iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
            iframe.src = 'page1.html';
            $('#iframe-holder').append(iframe);
        })

document.addEventListener(
'load',
function(event){
  //1:
  $($('#iframe-holder > iframe')[0].contentDocument).on('click', function (e) {
  console.log('ln34');
    });
  //2:    
  const iframe = document.querySelector('#iframe-holder > iframe');
    iframe.onload = function() {
        const iframeDocument = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        iframeDocument.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            console.log('ln43');
        })
    }
},
true // Capture event
);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="iframe-holder">
        
    </div>
</body>
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a click listener on the iframe itself here:

```js
    $(document).on('click','#iframe-holder > iframe',function(){
       console.log('you have clicked text in iframe');
       //do something
    });
```

Instead you should add a click event on the text in iframe, so you should do this:

```js
    const iframe = document.querySelector('#iframe-holder > iframe');
    iframe.onload = function() {
        const iframeDocument = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        iframeDocument.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'span') { // Element clicked inside iframe is a span element
                // Do your work here
            }
        }) 
    }
```

Comment: I'm having error `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame. at HTMLIFrameElement.iframe.onload`  for `iframe.contentWindow.document`

Comment: Use srcdoc instead of src, and pass the html directly instead of encoding it. The error will be gone